# Dúvida ao usar a resposta de uma Query no NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async

Bom, primeiramente, eu tenho dois arquivos: index.js que lida com as requisições e outro que faz o select no banco de dados, mas não sei como retornar ele para o client.

```
app.get('/pesqAlimentos', (req, res) => {
    pesqAlimentos(req.query.pesq.barraPesq);        
});
```

O código acima é do index.js.

```
function pesqAlimento(string){
    let str = string.toLowerCase().
    client.connect();
    client.query("SELECT * FROM pesquisaAlimentos('?')", [str]).then(res => 
    // aqui que não sei como retorno para o index as rows de 
    resposta para o index.js).catch(e => console.log(e))    
}
```

Este é o arquivo onde o select é feito. O que eu queria é conseguir retornar o res.rows, ou conseguir já mandá-lo como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tem uma função que retorna uma `promise`, basta utilizar o `await` para desempacotar o resultado nessa promise, dessa forma você pode não precisa de callbacks e pode simplificar o código:

```js
app.get('/pesqAlimentos', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let rows = await pesqAlimentos(req.query.pesq.barraPesq);
        res.send(rows);
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }      
});

async function pesqAlimento(string){
    let str = string.toLowerCase();
    client.connect();

    try {
        let res = await client.query("SELECT * FROM pesquisaAlimentos('?')", [str]);
        return res.rows;
    } finally {
        // Lembre de fechar a conexão. Um comando dentro do finally sempre 
        // irá rodar antes da função retornar ou lançar uma exceção
        client.close();
    }  
}
```

Você também irá precisar do modificador `async` nas funções que utilizam `await`, se não está familiarizado com `promises`, se informe com a documentação [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).